# pass java data into json and then get data from javascript

Tags: javascript, java

I was told that the way to send data from Java to JavaScript is to convert the Java data into JSon flat file and then read the file from JavaScript side. I wonder if anyone could show me a simple example. For example, in java, I have

> ArrayList arrlist = new ArrayList();
>
> arrlist.add("string1");
>
> arrlist.add("string2");
>
> arrlist.add("string3");
>
> arrlist.add("string4");
>
> arrlist.add("string5");

how could I really get the data in the ***arrlist*** from JavaScript side?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To put the contents of your list into JSON, you can use

```
JSONArray arrListJson = new JSONArray(arrList);
```

Answer (score 0):

For such purpose, it is really convenient to use a JSON library such as Jackson. Refer to [this link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json) for a quick start.

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure how to import ObjectMapper.

Comment: If you are using Maven, or another dependency management tool, add Jackson's dependency to your project.

Comment: Or else you can download the JAR from the Maven's search repository itself, and include it in your classpath. http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.5/jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar